# How to change the background of LinearLayout which is defined in a Cursor Adapter in Android

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

I have a cursor adapter and a custom layout. I want based on the value of

```
String result = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(5)));
```

to have different background of my linear layout which I try to change it inside my cursor adapter and inside in bindView like:

```
LinearLayout LinearGameItem = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.LinearItem);
    if(result.contains("Win"))
    {
        LinearGameItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F3FCDA"));
    }
```

And I get an error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
'void android.widget.LinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(int)' 
on a null object reference 
at com.cfriends.contacts.model.CursorAdapter.bindView
```

Comment: Could you give a little more context around the LinearGameItem code? What function is this code in? Is this inside of an Activity, Fragment, Adapter, etc? My initial thought is that you're calling setBackgroundColor() before the view is created.

Comment: As I said it is inside my Cursor Adapter's Bind View

Comment: Could you post the code immediately preceding this from your bindView() method?

Comment: it seems that your LinearGameItem  is null. it can be because of that there is no R.id.LinearItem in your view.

Comment: I just noticed that the id of Linear Layout was null at the 600sw-dp and 700sw-dp so for each I placed the same id

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that the id of Linear Layout was null at the 600sw-dp and 700sw-dp so for each I placed the same id